# Table going out of my container

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a rails app, and I am using bootswatch for the css. I have a page with a container and a table into it. However, the table goes out of the container, even if the content is super short.

Here is my html.erb page:

```
<div class="jumbotron col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-10">
  <h2><%= @user.name%></h2>
  <%= image_tag(@user.photo.url(:regular))%>
  <p><strong>Description: </strong> <%= @user.bio %> </p>
  <% if @user.privacy == 'public' %><p><strong>Email: </strong><%= @user.email %></p><% end%>
  <p><strong> Role: </strong> <%= @user.status.camelize %> </p>
  <p><strong>Compétences: </strong>
  <% @user.skills.each do |s| %>
  <span class="label label-success"><%= s.value.camelize%></span>
  <% end %>
  </p>
  <p><strong>Solde: </strong> <%= @user.amount %> </p>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="bs-component">
      <legend class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">Liste des projets de <%= current_user.name%></legend>
      <table class="table table-striped table-hover col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-6 ">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Nom du projet</th>
            <th>Description</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <% @projects.each do |project| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= link_to project.name, project_path(project.id) %></td>
            <td><%= project.description %></td>
          </tr>
          <% end %>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How should I do to avoid that ?
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I'd need to see a live preview at somewhere like https://jsfiddle.net/ to be able to play with it. Any chance you could recreate the problem there and post a link?

Comment: Yes sure, I will work on this right now and edit my post very soon. Thanks a lot

Comment: "Create responsive tables by wrapping any .table in .table-responsive" (from the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive).

Comment: I did not know how to use jsfiddle with bootstrap, but the responsive table solution looks like it work !